# How can I open a directory in Pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am configuring a button:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButtonExport, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()') ,self.'directory_to_open')
```

I don't know how to configure the slot to open a directory. For example `C:\Example`.

Comment: There's no such thing; You can ``os.listdir()`` and display the contents of the directory.

Comment: Connect the `clicked()` signal to a slot (i.e. a function, method, or any other python callable object). In the slot, put the code that shows the directory (e.g. [QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory)).

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you are asking - What do you mean by 'open a directory'?
Do you just want to get a reference to the path to the directory?

Assuming your button is inside another class:

```
button1 = QtGui.QPushButton("This is button1", self)
# set button to call somefunction() when clicked
buton1.clicked.connect(self.somefunction)

def somefunction(self):
    # this is called when button1 is clicked
    # put directory specific tasks here
    # examples:
    ddir = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Get Dir PAth")
    # ddir is a QString containing the path to the directory you selected
    print ddir  # this will output something like 'C://path/you/selected'
    # lets get a list of files from the directory:
    files = [name for name in os.listdir(str(ddir))]
    # txt files only:
    files = [name for name in os.listdir(str(ddir)) if name.endswith('.txt')]
    # jpg files only:
    files = [name for name in os.listdir(str(ddir)) if name.endswith('.jpg')]
    # now do something with your directory or list of files ...
```